# swift a func returns nil while it's still executing

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm lost with this idea that swift provide
let's jump ahead into the code that i have.

```
var someVar: [UIImage]!
init()
{
  someFunc() 
}
func someFunc() -> [UIImage]!
{
   postRequest.performRequestWithHandler({
            (responseData: NSData!, urlResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse!,error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult: AnyObject? =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err)
            let profileImageUrl = jsonResult!.objectForKey("profile_image_url") as! NSString
            var imageOfData: NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: profileImageUrl as String)!)

            self.someVar.append(UIImage(data: imageOfData)!) // #1


        })
  return self.someVar //#2

}
```

Let's assume that, this code works %100 and let's assume that this code is within `class foo()`

so if i created an instance of `Foo()` class within `viewController.swift` and called `someFunc()`, basically it will return an empty array of `[UIImage]!` because line #2 it will be executed before #1. let's take a look at `viewcontroller.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var image: [UIImage]!
   var someDecl: Foo = Foo()
   @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      self.image = self.someDecl.someVar

       self.img.image = self.image // an empty image or throw an exception 
     }
}
```

How to solve this issue ?, 
is my problem a multi-threading Problem ? 
if there are some documentations regarding my issue please give me a link where i can get some knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You haven't called `someFunc()`, and since your `someVar` is an optional, and not initialized,that's why it returns nil. If you don't want to call `someFunc()` and still want to assign `image` to `someVar` add the following to your class `Foo`.

```
init() {
 someVar=[UIImage]()
 //...
}
```

However, a better solution would be to change the code all together and do the following, :

```
func someFunc() -> [UIImage]!
{
   var someVar:[UIImage]!
   postRequest.performRequestWithHandler({
            (responseData: NSData!, urlResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse!,error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult: AnyObject? =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err)
            let profileImageUrl = jsonResult!.objectForKey("profile_image_url") as! NSString
            var imageOfData: NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: profileImageUrl as String)!)

            self.someVar.append(UIImage(data: imageOfData)!) // #1


        })
  return someVar //#2

}
```

And in ViewController :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var image: [UIImage]!
   var someDecl: Foo = Foo()
   @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      self.image = someDecl.someFunc()

       self.img.image = self.image[0] //or something else
     }
}
```

Also note that in the last line of the snippet above, you were setting `self.img.image` which is of type `UIImage!` to `[UIImage]!` which is an array of `UIImage`s. If you want to achieve a slideshow, you could use a delay and set the images one-by-one through a loop.

**EDIT:**

Use this [library](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for downloading images, It's a charm.

Comment: Sorry, i was typing everything very fast, just wanted to give the idea of my problem, even though Your code is producing the same Error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
according to your new Declaration of my function it will return someVar as a nil because it's still downloading the images from Internet  see the Capturing section it launch it in a new process, while continue executing the rest of the function code. i will edit my code Again

Comment: I found an library which will help you get rid of all the threading part which is causing to return nil. I'll just add that to the answer.

Comment: thank you :) ill test it and update a complete answer if it worked for me